# handleWatchKitExtentionRequest ... how do I access the reply element to return value to the watchkit extension?

Tags: swift, dictionary, watchkit

I know I must be doing something wrong with swift... the new API declares a pair of methods...

```
class func openParentApplication(_ userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!,
                       reply reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!,
                                      NSError!) -> Void)!) -> Bool
```

Which can be used in the watch kit extension... and

```
   func application(application: UIApplication!, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
```

which can be used in the parent application to handle the request....

I know I am doing something wrong, probably with swift, but the reply object is supposed to be where I can send information back to the extension, but I cannot figure out how to set values into the reply object/dictionary in the handlewatchkitextentionrequest method... I know its just me not understanding the swift syntax, but everything I have tried has failed... how do I put a value/define this dictionary? I have tried creating a dictionary and assigning it to reply, nope, tried to access elements of it no dice... I know this must be simple, but I am just not seeing it.

Answer (score 4):

**Watchkit Extension:**

```
// Call the parent application from Apple Watch

// values to pass
let parentValues = [
    "value1" : "Test 1",
    "value2" : "Test 2"
]

WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(parentValues, reply: { (replyValues, error) -> Void in
    println(replyValues["retVal1"])
    println(replyVaiues["retVal2"])
})
```

**iOS App:**

```
// in AppDelegate.swift
func application(application: UIApplication!, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
    // retrieved parameters from Apple Watch
    println(userInfo["value1"])
    println(userInfo["value2"])

    // pass back values to Apple Watch
    var retValues = Dictionary<String,String>()

    retValues["retVal1"] = "return Test 1"
    retValues["retVal2"] = "return Test 2"

    reply(retValues)
}
```

Comment: for watchOS 2   func application(application: UIApplication!, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!)  is not working ,  in watch OS 2  WCSession  is used i know that.. but how to handle that in handleWatchKitExtensionRequest  ???

Answer (score 1):

Wow, why was this so hard to find an answer too, apparently this is the proper way 
inside the

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
```

you send it back via:

```
reply(["x":"y"])
```